# StackExchange.Redis timeout exceptions

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, stackexchange.redis

I've got an Azure WebApp running on .net 4.5 using Umbraco 7.15.5 that experiences increasing response time under high load moments.

We had some exception regarding Stackexchange.Redis (v 2.1.58) but i don't know if that's the primary cause of the problems.

The metrics about the webapp CPU and Memory of the resource are ok but we detected an alert on the azure portal about Handle Count.

"High Handle Count was detected for the app"

[View Handle count Azure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3vSQ.png)

The redis exceptions are like:

StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET (5000ms), next: GET EventMessages:4003038, inst: 139, qu: 0, qs: 137, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint: xxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: RD28187861AF16, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=10,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=652,Free=32115,Min=150,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

or

StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET (5000ms), inst: 1, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint: xxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: RD28187832A927, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=10,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=550,Free=32217,Min=150,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Redis is configured with a ConnectionMultiplexer pool using this code to get the database:

```
private static IDatabase GetDatabase()
        {
            var leastPendingTasks = long.MaxValue;
            ConnectionMultiplexer leastPendingConnection = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < _pool.Length; i++)
            {
                var connection = _pool[i];
                if (connection == null)
                {
                    _pool[i] = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_connString);
                    return _pool[i].GetDatabase();
                }

                var pending = connection.GetCounters().TotalOutstanding;
                if (pending < leastPendingTasks)
                {
                    leastPendingTasks = pending;
                    leastPendingConnection = connection;
                }
            }

            return leastPendingConnection.GetDatabase();
        }
```

I thought there was a thread theft problem and I added this line to the webapp startup code
`ConnectionMultiplexer.SetFeatureFlag ("preventthreadtheft", true);`
but it didn't help.

Is there something i'm missing?

I hope I have filled in enough information to get the problem.

##### EDIT 03/02/2022

I tried to set `setMinThreads` to 1000 to see if something change.

I noticed the same result but the exception, but:

- The increasing response time were delayed than before.
- the instance that create problem is only 1 of 8 in total. That instance died for approx 15 min and then returns available.
- The current thread keeps increasing all day, see [Thread count graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUVAh.png)

Just to give other infos:

- the webapp uses server sent events during the high traffic moments to push messages to clients connected
- there is an application gateway in front of the webapp

##### EDIT 10/02/2022

We solved the issue, Redis was not the primary problem.
The server sent events code used to push messages to users  was not properly disposed and kept threads unnecessarily allocated without releasing it.
This caused a continuous increase in the number of threads until the webapp crashes.

We solved with some changes to the server sent events code.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a worker thread scaling issue. Your min is 150, which means that until 150 are in use, the thread pool will spawn new threads as needed until it hits at least that number, beyond which it *may* spawn new threads, or it *may* wait for other threads to become available. Once you hit the min thread count, in other words, you can't necessarily count on how quickly threads are going to be created. As an experiment, what happens if you do a `setMinThreads` of 1000 at startup? Does the problem go away? Does it delay the point at which you experience timeouts?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try as soon as possibile. I recently moved from 2 to 150 min threads without solve the issue, I can try set 1000 and see if something change. Thanks

Comment: Note here that my suggestion isn't necessarily a *solution* - it could solve the problem, but it could shine some light on the behavior.

Comment: And it won't get rid of high handle count warnings.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I updated the question with other infos, i don't know if this can help to understand the problem better. Thanks in advance

Comment: How many instances are there on this app service plan? If more than one, can you apply splitting by instance?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I'll reply on behalf of mazzod (I'm one of his coworkers).
We are running with either 3, 6 or 8 instances.
Thread count and handle are roughly the same for each instance (differences are minimal). We are trying to pinpoint what is exhausting the threads, we are currently looking at the Server-Sent Event code.

Comment: @Matteo, that seems like a good path to follow - one possibility here is that your event code and the Redis client are competing for threads.

Comment: I don't think this will help your issue, but if someone else with a similar issue arrives on this page. This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html